# Print full page delphi

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-xe

Whenever I print a from in delphi, it does not print to the entire page. It uses all the page horizontally, but it only uses about 3/4 of the page vertically.

My code is :

```
printer.Orientation:=poLandscape;
form1.PrintScale:=poPrintToFit;
printer.Copies:=spinedit1.Value;
form1.Print;
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks

I have tried changing form sizes and trying other printers will no result, it prints exactly the same thing.

Comment: May your form's aspect ratio be causing it? Increase form's height to test if this is the case.

Comment: Also check your printer border settings to see if they are not interfering with your final result.

Comment: As SilverWarrior said: *Can* your printer print to the paper edges?

Comment: What is the size of your form (in pixels) and the paper (in inches or mm). Since you are printing in Landscape orientation what do you mean when you say 3/4 of page vertically? Vertically when you have the paper turned into landscape? With your settings I get a printout all the way to the edges, except the non-printable area, approx 5 mm. Tested with form (w x h) 553 x 383 pixels on 210 x 297mm paper (ratio 0.71).

Comment: Size of form is 1056 x 1963. I'm using A4 paper, so that's 11.7 x 8.3 inches. I mean when holding the page horizontally, it does not print to the bottom of the page, it only prints approx 3/4 to the bottom, it prints all the way to edge horizontally but not vertically if you get me.

Comment: Are you quite sure of the  height of your form? I'd ask the form to report its actual height before printing.

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% it's the size of my form. I've tried it on new VCL forms, and on different printers with exactly the same results. I've printed the form to one note and saved the result, here's what's being printed - 
![http://oi62.tinypic.com/11v1ffa.jpg](http://i62.tinypic.com/11v1ffa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exactly what you want.  The printer is producing an image of the screen that is 1963 by 1056 which should map nicely on to the top 3/4 of your 11.7 x 8.3 paper.  The top 3/4 would be about 11.7 x 6.2.  (1963/1056 is approximately equal to 11.7/6.2)  You are printing an image with the aspect ration of about 2 to 1; the printed image has the same aspect ratio.  If the printed image filled the entire page, it would be distorted in such a way that it looked either too tall or too narrow, depending on your perspective.  You would see this more clearly if you were to throw some other controls onto the form near the corners.  They will show up on the printed page.

Comment: How can I get/force it to use the entire A4 page when printing ? Thanks for your reaponse!

Comment: Take a look at Delphi Help topic TCustomForm.PrintScale.  You used poPrintToFit which I think is your best choice.  You can select poProportional or poNone and see whether one of them suits your needs better.  To make an image fill the page you could change the proportions of your window to a multiple of 11.7 x 8.3, say 1170 x 830 or 1755 x 1245